H^2 of symmetric group
I'm a number theorist in need of some group cohomology lemmas, and I'm rather bewildered by the level of generality used in the literature. Specifically, the result I need is as follows: the restriction map
$$
  H^2(S_m, \mathbb{Z}/2\mathbb{Z}) \to H^2(S_{m-1}, \mathbb{Z}/2\mathbb{Z})
$$
is injective for all but finitely many $m$ ($m \geq 3$?).
I'm confused by the following:

GroupProps only lists homology $H_k(S_m, \mathbb{Z})$. Is cohomology the dual of this, or is that valid only over a field?
They also list the stable homology, meaning that for large $m$, $H^k(S_m, \mathbb{Z})$ is constant. Is it also known that the restriction maps are isomorphisms in the region of stability?
Adem–Milgram (here Chapter VI is on the symmetric groups) give results on the cohomology ring $H^*(\mathcal{S}_\infty, \mathbb{F}_p)$. As I read p. 182 (in the 1994 edition), it seems to say that dimension $2$ should only occur for $n = 1, i_1 = 2$ which has bidegree $2$ so the cohomology should stabilize at $S_2$. Is this correct, or does it take till $S_4$ as with the integral homology?


Since you say that you are interested only in the case of coefficients in $\mathbb Z/2\mathbb Z$, which is a field, it's OK if you need to use duality results valid only over a field, isn't it?

More is true: the $d^{\text{th}}$ cohomology group of $S_n$ with coefficients in any abelian group $R$ stabilizes as $n \mapsto \infty$, so the maps are actually isomorphisms (not just injections).
By universal coefficients, it is enough to prove this for $R = \mathbb{Z}$ and for homology rather than cohomology.  The theorem in question was then originally proved by Nakaoka in
M. Nakaoka, Decomposition theorem for homology groups of symmetric groups, Ann. of Math. (2) 71 (1960), 16-42.
It follows from his results that for $n > 2d$, the map $H_d(S_{n-1}) \rightarrow H_d(S_n)$ is an isomorphism.
This has been re-proved and generalized many times.  Some lecture notes by Kupers with my favorite way of proving it are available here.

Your map is an isomorphism for $m\geqslant 5$ and $m=3$. For $m=4$ it is surjective but not injective. The group $H^2(S_m,\mathbb{Z}/2)$ is $\mathbb{Z}/2$ for $m= 2$ and $m=3$, and $\mathbb{Z}/2\oplus \mathbb{Z}/2$ for $m\geqslant 4$. And yes, in any degree, in the stable range, restriction is an isomorphism.
To answer your integral question, for a finite group $G$, universal coefficients give an isomorphism between $H^i(G,\mathbb{Z})$ and $\operatorname{\rm Ext}^1_{\mathbb Z}(H_{i-1}(G,\mathbb{Z}),\mathbb{Z})$, which is isomorphic to $\operatorname{\rm Hom}(H_{i-1}(G,\mathbb{Z}),\mathbb{C}^\times)$. This is the Pontrjagin dual of $H_{i-1}(G,\mathbb{Z})$. So $H^i(G,\mathbb{Z})$ and $H_{i-1}(G,\mathbb{Z})$ are dual abelian groups.
